# nginx redirecting to parent directory not sub drirectory

Tags: php, apache, nginx, laravel-5.1, ubuntu-14.04

nginx default config file

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     domain.com;
  root            /var/www/html/laravel5-1.0/;
  index       index.php;

  location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

   #proxy_cache web_cache;
   add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

   proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
  }


  # CSS and Javascript
  location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }

}
```

**Problem**: nginx pointing to `www` directory not the `laravel5-1.0` directory application type is `laravel`

`laravel5` is the public directory for my application 
nginx and apache running on the same virtual host machine 
nginx port 80 apache2 8081

please help me to redirect my page access to laravel5-1.0 directory

Answer (score 1):

`try_files` does just that, it checks for `$uri` if it doesn't find that, it will do an internal redirect to `/index.php` before the proxy_pass.
So if you remove the line 
`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;`

It will reach the proxy_pass to http://localhost:8081/

Doc:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files